A movie where a son is cut to death by a tractor blades?
This movie had a scene where a son was plowing a field with a tractor that had rolling blades on it and I remember that the son hit something and fell in front of the tractor and he got cut up and died. The mother came out to check on him and she found him bloodied and she might have had blonde hair and she was holding him crying. The son was probably close to 18-20 years old and was sleeveless.

Is it "The Man in the Moon" (1991)? 

When Maureen leaves for home, Court goes back to plowing the fields and falls off the tractor, and is badly injured. Dani sees this, and races home to tell her father. When Matthew returns home, he has some of Court's blood on his clothes and the family realizes that Court has died. Maureen hides her pain at first, while Dani bursts into tears.

The clip in the trailer starting at 2:07 looks about right. Take a look and see if that's the one you're describing. 




Great movie, IMO.

The movie is called, "Man in the Moon" from 1991. It was Reese Witherspoon's first movie! It's a beautiful story with a very tragic and unexpected ending. The early 90s had several films like this another such film was "My Girl."

What does this add to the already accepted answer?

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2374902/?ref_=nv_sr_2
Is it this movie from island?

Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. Especially as this question has an accepted answer.
